# parameter connection problem. How can I deal with this

Tags: javascript, typescript, parameters, callback

Unfortunately, I got a chaos in my understanding.

```
function sendRequest(data: string, cb: (response: any) => void) {
  return cb({ data: "Hi there!" });
}

sendRequest("Send this!", response => {
  console.log(response);
  return true;
}
```

I thought the result is { "Send this!" : "Hi there!} 
But the answer is {data : "Hi there!"}

**what can't the parameter "data" be connected to the data inside the object?
And If I want that result, what should I change?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is due to your object understanding `data` as the name of the key and is not trying to get the content of the variable. You need to put `[data]` so it will resolve to the string inside your variable.
You can just do this : `return cb({ [data]: "Hi there!" });`

Comment: It is really clear! and succinct. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Don't forget to add the answers that helped you as Correct answers so people having the same problem can find the same solution. =)

Comment: Sorry I am a novice of stackoverflow. I clicked the tick. is that correctly you ask me to do?

Comment: @AndersonKim Yep ! =)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do that, you could do:

```
function sendRequest(data: string, cb: (response: any) => void) {
  let result = {};
  result[data] = "Hi there!";
  return cb(result);
}

sendRequest("Send this!", response => {
  console.log(response);
  return true;
});
```